# JAXB renaming attributes by itself

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, rename

In my XSD I have the following attribute:

```
<xs:element name="id8digits" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

But when i use JAXB to generate java-classes it renames it to:

```
@XmlElement(name = "id8digits", namespace = "my.org.name")
protected String id8Digits; // Capital D instead of lower case d
```

The XSD is delivered by a third party, and I cannot change the XSD itself. I have read about bindings-files, but even if I rename the attribute to `id8digits` with a lower case d, JAXB renames it again to upper case D.

I have also tried to use globalbindings and set `enableJavaNamingConventions="false"` but that does not do the trick.

**bindings.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1"><jxb:bindings schemaLocation="XSD.xsd">
<jxb:globalBindings enableJavaNamingConventions="false"/>
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='id8digits']">
    <jxb:property name="id8digits"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Is this causing an issue somewhere, as i think the mapping will be done with `XmlElement(name = "id8digits", namespace = "my.org.name")` and not the java variable name.

Comment: @RaviRanjan That is not what I experience. I have a temporary workaround for this problem by annotating the setId8Digits()-method with @JsonProperty("id8digits"). But I cannot use this solution in production as I am tampering with generated files.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem somewhere else:-

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {

    @XmlElement(name = "id8digits", namespace = "my.org.name")
    protected String id8Digits;

    public String getId8Digits() {
        return id8Digits;
    }

    public void setId8Digits(String id8Digits) {
        this.id8Digits = id8Digits;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        Test jaxbElement = new Test();
        jaxbElement.setId8Digits("Testing");
        m.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }
}
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Test xmlns:ns2="my.org.name"><ns2:id8digits>Testing</ns2:id8digits></Test>
```

Comment: The reason I found this problem is because when the input is consumed, there is no implicit mapping between the `int id8Digits` variable at my consumer and the `id8digits` that is passed to it.

My temporary solution is to add a @JsonProperty, but I'd rather not do this in production since I am tampering with generated files.